# What Happened to Helpful Flags Counter on User Page?

Tags: discussion, flagging, user-interface

What happened to the 'Helpful Flags' counter / link that was available on your user page as it seems to have disappeared today?

Comment: Moreover, my available flags dropped from almost 90 to almost 60 (both numbers are upper bounds).

Comment: And it's suddenly back. But the numbers have changed.

Comment: Hah! Now it jumped up to 100.

Comment: I think you can't go above 100... (Flags available, not helpful flags.)

Comment: Yes. I was talking about flags remaining. I think I had over 1200 helpful flags, but now I have 1197. I might be misremembering and I actually had 1172, though. In that case it makes sense how my available flags jumped up.

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: My numbers (helpful (530->546) and available (32->59) flags) also changed and in the past there was always a [mismatch](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/8297/19341) between "comments flagged", "deemed helpful" and "declined" due to old flags. This seems to be fixed...

Comment: @AsafKaragila How did you get that many available flags!?

Comment: @Potato: I raised over 1200 helpful flags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jarrod Dixon recently finished a major flag-related project he's been working on for a few months. In his own words,

> We're rolling out a massive refactoring around flags, including how and where they're stored in the database.

Some of the related Meta.SO threads:

- [Flag count is missing from profile pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185866/224469)
- [On the recent changes to flagging and limits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185888/224469)
- [Flags are broken on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184176/224469)

One minor change that I just noticed myself: flagging a question as a duplicate now inserts the same auto-comment that voting to close does.

Comment: Why would you flag a question as a duplicate, when you can vote to close it as a duplicate?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Um, $1085<3000$... I believe that users able to vote to close do not even see the category of flags to close.